# Android storing large number of images

Tags: android, image

I'm building an app that requires to store a large number of images and I'm unsure what is the best way of storing them.
I don't have any restrictions in terms of implementation but the images will be in 2 different sizes for mobile and tablet devices.

I want to keep my app as fast and responsive as possible.

basically I'm unsure if I should:

1) store the images in a server and view them in a webview

2) store the images somewhere on the device and reference them in a database.

3) store the images in the database

also I'm unsure how big the images are going to be, will this cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer without knowing the nature of your app, but in general images *size* is more important factor than images *number*.

I would avoid storing the images in the database, it will be more cumbersome than useful.

You might run into problem if your app size growing indefinitely as more images become available. What I would normally do, is to store the core images (that more likely to be used) on the device and the rest on the server and load them as needed.

It is helpful to watch the total size of your images on the device to limit the storage use to a reasonable size.

To make your app more responsive and memory efficient at the same time, consider using [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)